# SwiftUI Circle changing trim attribute moves the Circle shadow

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, shadow

I am trying to apply a shadow to a Circle. If I change the trim attribute of the Circle, the shadow moves away (unexpectedly). I want that the shadow sits under the trimmed part of the Circle. How can I do that?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let trimValue: CGFloat = 0.5
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Text("trimValue is \(trimValue.description)")
            
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0, to: trimValue)
                .stroke(lineWidth: 40)
                .fill(Color.white)
                .shadow(
                    color: Color.gray.opacity(0.4),
                    radius: 30,
                    x: 14,
                    y: 14)

        }.frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    }
}
```

[image: First image is how I want it to look like]

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

Comment: Strange. SwiftUI 1.0 is a real mess!